# SLF4j based logs in GAE always shows up as warning level

Tags: google-app-engine, slf4j

I am logging some messages at various levels using slf4j on google app engine but when I deploy the application the logs all show up at WARN level. Am I messing up the config some how?

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger log = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogExample.class);
log.debug("debug");
log.error("error");
log.info("info");
log.warn("warn");
```

[image]

Logging.properties

```
# A default java.util.logging configuration.
# (All App Engine logging is through java.util.logging by default).
#
# To use this configuration, copy it into your application's WEB-INF
# folder and add the following to your appengine-web.xml:
# 
# <system-properties>
#   <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
# </system-properties>
#

# Set the default logging level for all loggers
.level = WARNING

# Set the default logging level for ORM, specifically, to WARNING
DataNucleus.JDO.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Persistence.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Cache.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.MetaData.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.General.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Utility.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Transaction.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Datastore.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ClassLoading.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Plugin.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.ValueGeneration.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.Enhancer.level=WARNING
DataNucleus.SchemaTool.level=WARNING

com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter.level=INFO
```

Comment: Can you post you logging config files?

Comment: Looks like your config is being ignored.  It is showing info but not debug which I believe is the default.  Verify that you have the system property configured like the property file's comments indicate and make sure your logging file is getting bundled into the WEB-INF directory.

Comment: Oh meant to add that you'll want to add that system property to your appengine-web.xml file most likely.

Comment: I had to truncate this config file to obfuscate some internal classes but it is filtering levels correctly and being added to the package.

Comment: So are there any handlers in that config file?

Comment: No just level mappings

Comment: Well sorry man I don't know.  Thought maybe this was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your config being ignored.
Add this to `appengine-web.xml`

```
<!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
<system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```